# Jersey: Can I add a cookie in ContainerResponseFilter?

Tags: cookies, jersey, jax-rs, servlet-filters

I have a `ContainerResponseFilter` and I tried to set a cookie in it as follows:

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
    String cookieName = "ExampleCookie";
    String cookieValue = "SomeData";
    logger.info("Setting cookie " + cookieName + " with value " + cookieValue + " into cookies " + JsonUtils.objectToJson(containerResponseContext.getCookies()));
    containerResponseContext.getCookies().put(cookieName, new NewCookie(cookieName, cookieValue));
}
```

But this give the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:203) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
```

It is not possible to set the cookie here?  If it is, how would I do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yeah seems a bit odd that this is not allowed. Not sure why this is not allowed. I've tested both with Jersey and Resteasy. With Resteasy, all that happens is that the cookie is not set (no Exception). I'm thinking some operation sets the cookies as headers, and by the time the filter is reached, no further operation is done with the cookies.

The only work around I can think of is to simply set the header yourself

```
responseContext.getHeaders().add("Set-Cookie", new NewCookie("Hello", "World"));
```

The `toString()` of `NewCookie` will return how it should look in the header

```
Set-Cookie: Hello=World;Version=1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for having a look.  I think the headers approach is straightforward.

Comment: As to the oddness, REST is designed to be stateless. A cookie implies state.

Comment: @peeskillet if we send a new cookie from browser..do webservers send them back to browser by default? I'm testing with postman and observed it.

Comment: @peeskillet Actually I'm outgoing cookies from responseContext..server is not redirecting cookies from browser...but I see cookies in browser cookies...postman/browser also saves cookies which are not sent by server but by themselves?

Comment: Just for integrate this correct answer, you can also use HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE constant in place of "Set-Cookie" literal