# Adding cookie to all responses in Jersey / JAX-RS (Scala)

Tags: java, scala, cookies, jersey, jax-rs

Thought this would be a common use case but I'm coming up short.  Also, I'm using Scala but a Java answer would be fine, too.

In Jersey I'd like to set a simple cookie on all responses coming out of my app.

A quick google shows that I can set cookies on a single response by performing the following:

`return Response.ok(new Viewable("/index", model))
     .cookie(new NewCookie("name", "Hello, world!"))
     .build();`

That's great if I just want to set a cookie on a per-response basis, but I want it on every response.  This seems like a job for middleware.  The [Jersey Docs recommend this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#10.2.1) for setting up middleware:

```
class MyResponseMiddleware ContainerResponseFilter {
  override def filter(req: ContainerRequestContext, res: ContainerResponseContext) = {
    // do stuff here
  }  
}
```

The problem is there's no way to set a cookie on the `ContainerResponseContext` as `.getCookies` returns a read-only map, unlike `.getHeaders()` which is mutable.

I also tried to create a cookie by setting the headers:

`containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, new NewCookie(...))` but this did not make it to the browser.

It seems like if I could get a reference to `ServletResponse` or `HttpServletResponse` this would [be simple](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie(javax.servlet.http.Cookie)) but that doesn't appear to be possible in Jersey's middleware (filters).

This seems like a pretty straightforward use-case so I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Have you verified that the filter is being called?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954305/jersey-can-i-add-a-cookie-in-containerresponsefilter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply Inject **HttpServletResponse** into the filter.
Use @Context annotation as follows.

```
@Provider
public class ResponseHTTPStatusFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter{
@Context HttpServletResponse resp;
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
       resp.addCookie(cookie);
    }

}
```